# User is getting Access Denied when trying to add new document from a customer content type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, document-template

I have a user that is trying to add a document to a library using the New Document button. I signed in using his credentials and it worked fine, but when he tries from his computer he gets the access denied. He can upload a document fine and edit documents already in the library but he can't use the default Document template or the custom "Narrative" template we created. It is just the one user with the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This was an VDI issue and not a SharePoint issue.